# Why "echo ${ARRAY[0]}" behavours different between run script directory vs source it?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script (array_test.sh) as below:

```
ARRAY=()
v="FOO"
ARRAY+=(${v})
v="BAR"
ARRAY+=(${v})

echo ${ARRAY[@]}
echo ${#ARRAY[@]}
echo ${ARRAY[0]}
```

When I run that script directly (./array_test.sh), I got the result as below:

```
FOO BAR
2
FOO
```

But when I source it (source ./array_test.sh), the last `FOO` is missing:

```
FOO BAR
2
```

Is that a bug or something wrong in my tiny script?

Comment: Does it change if you put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but FYI, you're misunderstanding what quotation marks are for in Bash: you're including them when they do absolutely nothing, and leaving them out when they're potentially useful. If you Google `Bash quotation marks`, you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. Tried with both bash 3.2.57 and 4.2.37.

Comment: @ruakh Maybe, or `awk`. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ZSh, and perhaps some other shells, arrays are indexed from 1 rather than from 0.

So the problem is most likely that your command-line shell is not Bash. When you're running your script as an executable in its own process, it's running in Bash (or a shell that behaves as Bash does); when you're `source`-ing it inside your command-line shell, it's running in ZSh (or a shell that behaves as ZSh does).

(Hat-tip to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comment above, now deleted, that set me on this line of thought.)